# how to draw large grids for map editor?

Tags: java, user-interface, paint, bufferedimage, heap-memory

I'm making a map editor for my 2d tile based RPG game, and I'm running into a roadblock. The problem is actually how to draw the grid lines efficiently for very large maps like, say 300x300 tiles.

Originally I called redrew the entire grid panel every time you moved the mouse or clicked(since it allows you to drag and also highlights the tile you are hovering over). This was horrible for large maps and was very slow.

So my solution was to create a bufferedImage for the grid of a specified size right when a new empty map was created, and redraw that image every time paint was called. This worked very well, except that for anything above 200x200ish java would run out of heap space in creating that bufferedImage. I can't really have a preloaded image because the user should be able to specify a new map to be any size. Also, I like the grid to be drawn over the tiles, otherwise the tiles cover up the lines and it looks messier. That means the grid has to be drawn again every time tiles are added right?

My question is, is there another way to draw a very large grid that will repaint each time you move the mouse? 
The program Tiled can easily create maps of 1000x1000 or more, how is it done?? Thanks

**EDIT:**
I mean the actual grid LINES, not the grid content such as tiles. Right now when the grid is drawn it iterates through the 2D array and draws a line at every length of a tile.

**EDIT:**
I got it to work by painting only the visible portion of the screen. Turns out it's not that hard to find the coordinates of the view pane in a JScrollPane. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is similair I guess to what im working on at the moment.  I am currently writing a bit of simulation software with a 3D frontend in Ogre3D.  I have a tile based map that can be easily 3000 x 3000 sometimes they may be even larger.

Now im not sure how you are going about drawing your grid, if you are just doing 2D/3D, but the main problem for me was how to apply different textures to each tile.  If this isnt relevant then hopefully this may help anyway for future lol.  The problem for me is that creating a seperate object for eacch tile is a no no, due to speed.  If there are even 1024 x 1024 your looking at over 1 million tiles, each with attributes.  This worked great on my first tests where I only had 10 x 10 maps but on larger maps it just ground to a halt.

What I am currently doing is rewriting it, the new approach is as follows.  (You may be able to adapt this for what you are doing if it helps).  The grid is now only 1 object, its a mesh in my case as im working in 3d.  Each vertex holds a couple of values, one is the column and one is the row.  I have a seperate texture which is the same size as my map, so for a map with 100 columns and 100 rows i create a texture 100 x 100 (this is created dynamically).

I then pass this texture and the vertices to my cg shader (this is where tyou may have to think of an equivalent way of doing things, but I think it should be doable).  By looking up the colour at the pixel in this texture relating to the grid slot I want to texture I can find a colour value, these colour values relate to my texture atlas which holds all my possible textures for my map.  All you then have to do is use that particular part of the texture atlas for that particular part of the mesh / grid.

I hope that makes some sort of sense, if not then id be happy to explain a bit more.  I think even though im using CG shaders, you should be able to come up with an equivalent for non CG based stuff in java.  The advantage of this is that you end up with one lookup texture, one object in memory and a buffer holding your vertices which is very quick for lookup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, my problem is a bit different, sorry I was unclear. I'm having trouble with how to draw the actual grid lines, the squares. I'm already drawing the tiles in the same way that you suggested where a single hashmap holds all the images and each tile just contains a variable that is the key to the corresponding image.